# How to prevent orientation changes in windows phone 8.1 apps

Tags: screen-orientation, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app that in most of the pages requires (ok, allows) orientation changes to happen (by handling changes using visual state manager), but I have some of the pages where I want to disable the orientation change to happen.

How can I disable the orientation change for these pages? There is no SupportedOrientations property for the Page anymore (like in WP 8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the supported orientation, use the `DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences` property:

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
```

Note that this property is global, and not set just on the page like it was on previous versions of Windows Phone. If you want to apply the change to only one page, override the `OnNavigatedTo` event and set the value there. Just don't forget to restore the previous value when the user leaves the page, either using `OnNavigatedFrom` or the `OnNavigatedTo` event of the next page.